# jquery to unsave jobs on Linkedin

Tags: jquery, linkedin-api

I have a lot of Saved jobs in my LinkedIN Jobs list
My ideea was to create a jQruery statement that can unsave more of them all at once so don't do 1000 clicks. 
Currently, on the LINKEDIN JOBS page, you have to click **"..."** button, then **->** **"Unsave"** button (which has a **ribbon** icon) 
I've only came up with this, which I have to re-execute in the console

```
$("[type='ribbon-icon']").click()
```

My jQuery is a bit rusty 
Can anyone do a better one?

Answer (score 0):

Are you intending to use Greasemonkey or something similar?  If so, the following should do the trick. Note that jQuery is required, whatever method you use.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        LinkedIn - Remove All Saved Jobs
// @namespace   linkedinremovejobs
// @description Remove all saved jobs from LinkedIn with a single click
// @include https://www.linkedin.com/my-items/saved-jobs/
// @require https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var checkInt;

$(window).load(function() {
  checkInt = setInterval(checkForSavedButton, 1000);
});

function checkForSavedButton(){
    if ($("button[id='ember45']").length > 0){
    clearInterval(checkInt);
    $(".search-reusables__filter-list").append('<li class="search-reusables__primary-filter"><button id="li_rem_jobs" class="artdeco-pill artdeco-pill--slate artdeco-pill--2 artdeco-pill--choice search-reusables__filter-list" type="button">Remove All</button></li>');
    $("#li_rem_jobs").on("click",function(){
      $("li.reusable-search__result-container").each(function(){
        $(this).find("li-icon[type='ribbon-icon']").trigger("click");
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Essentially, it waits until the 'Saved' button is visible, and then adds a 'Remove All' button.  Upon clicking this, it enumerates the job containers and triggers a click on each ribbon icon.

[image]

**This removes all saved jobs!** You might want to add a JavaScript 'confirm' command, so you've got a chance to cancel before accidentally trashing all your jobs; let me know if you need an example of this.

Also note that this might break if LinkedIn change their DOM structure or CSS.  I've just run this in my LinkedIn account and it appears to work as expected. Let me know if it works at your end.

Comment: Currently this snippet works -> https://gist.github.com/matale/8b7c0fd8425c60ebe6db0c08bc82607b